# Angular - image onload event in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need the dimensions of an image loaded from the web (dynamically) to adapt my display. So I need to use an onload event in the controller (the view is not rendered yet), like so :

```
.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
    img.onload = function () {
        // $scope changes not effective
}
```

I know I could use `$apply`, but I'm not a huge fan of it since it hurts performances. Do you have any other solution I could use, whether for Angular to be aware of what I'm doing (which is not the case with `img.onload`) or for the scope to take my changes into account?

Thanks!

Comment: Controllers should never be aware of the DOM attached to them. I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do? You want to tell the image what size to be based on some server response, or are you trying to get the dimensions of the image and use them in your controller?

Comment: I'm not trying to get anything from the DOM, just, as you said in second, get the dimension of the image and use them in my controller. Which is not possible until the image have loaded, if I'm not wrong - that's why I used `img.onload`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `directive` to fetch the image properties, and assign them to your scope in the controller. Here is some pseudo-code, can't guarantee it'll 100% work out of the box, but it should give you an idea on what needs to happen.

**Template**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <img img-size src="..." />
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('imgSize', function() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('load', function(e) {
                var width = $(this).width();
                var height: $(this).height();

                scope.$evalAsync(function() {
                    scope.imageWidth = width;
                    scope.imageHeight = height;
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a solution I thought about a lot, but as I said the view is not rendered yet - and I don't want to display the image yet, since its container styling depends a lot on its dimensions. A loader is displayed until the `img.onload` finishes. I guess I will have to use `$apply`, in the end...

Comment: Don't use `$apply`, you'll just run into conflicts with Angular's own digest cycle. This is what `$evalAsync` is for - it will run during the current digest if possible, or in the next one, like `$timeout` would.

Comment: So you say I should take a look into `$evalAsync` and that's my best bet ?

Comment: Any changes to the scope you do outside of Angular's digest cycle will not update the DOM. For instance, the `load` event. When you use `ng-click` or any other directive, angular handles `$apply` for you. In order for your DOM to update when you change the scope outside of Angular, you need to call `$evalAsync` on your scope, or `$timeout`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will wait for a little bit and mark your answer as accepted, since you provided me the most help here. You're great.

Answer (score 0):

Use a directive that will inject the height/width in the the controller $scope.

```
<img height-width />
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. The image is not in the view (yet), I want to get the dimension of the image and use them in my controller before the view renders. That's why I used `img.onload`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your image in the current View. You could access it with something like:

```
var elImage = document.getElementById("[your_imageId]")
```

After that

```
elImage .addEventListener('load', function() { /* ... */ }, false);
```

should get you further.

Comment: While this will technically work, this is not the correct solution. Controllers should never have DOM element queries inside of them.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. The image is not in the view (yet), I want to get the dimension of the image and use them in my controller before the view renders. That's why I used `img.onload`